# Getting Epubjs-rn working

Tags: react-native, epub.js

I can't get this library working. I've followed the [directions](https://github.com/futurepress/epubjs-rn/blob/master/README.md#getting-started) but end up with this error at runtime.

> the package [...]/node_modules/epubjs-rn/package.json was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a main module field that could not be resolved